# Lord of Light—why is it a pun, and what is the pun?

Tags: religion, lord-of-light

I've just read the book and can't figure out why "Lord of Light" is a pun.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that title _is_ a pun?

Answer (score 15):

Lord of Light isn't a pun. The book is infamous for a really bad one, though:

> The fit hit the Shan (the Shan being a local noble who was just put into the body of someone with a seizure disorder, and it of course being a play on *The shit hit the fan*)